# Archlinux Dell XPS graphic glitches even in Bios

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux

today, suddenly chrome died on me and the bottom half of my screen on my dell xps 15 7590 started flickering and kind of mirroring the windows above.

I have tried reinstalling intel and nouvou drivers, installed lts kernel, tried switching from i3 to gnome and some options within the xinitrc, nomodeset & i915.enable_psr=0. To no avail.

Is the graphics card dead?

Any ideas what else I could try? Any other info that could help denug this that I can provide?

**Edit** it seems to be a display issue. I connected to an external
Monitor on which ghere are no graphic issues. Still a hardware problem on the internal display of the device?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the Bios is showing the problem it will a hardware failure.

Comment: "Is the graphics card dead?" - It's possible.  It's also possible the problem is the display itself.  If you connect an external display are the graphical glitches you are experiencing displayed on the external display.

Comment: @Ramhound this morning I had a chance to connect to an external display. It does indeed seem to be a display issue, since on the external monitor everything is fine.

Comment: This is a non-reproducible hardware issue. According to the Dell support the screen needs replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Update: According to the Dell support the screen needs replacing.